# perl DBI mysql server has gone away - Not a timeout issue

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

There have been many posts with this question, so let me be clear about the salient features:

- it happens with perl DBI
- it happens with a $db->do('delete rows from table where condition')
- it happens immediately after the db object is created, ie the statement never succeeds, ever
- it happens with a script that works perfectly on my workstation but does not work on the server
- the mysql versions on both machines are the same:
  mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

I always get this error:

DBD::mysql::db do failed: MySQL server has gone away at (eval 18)[/usr/share/perl5/perl5db.pl:646] line 2

DBI_TRACE=1 does not reveal anything in particular

What could be causing this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running [mysqlcheck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will check that function out. However, it is used to check tables and in this case it was the server I could not communicate with.

Comment: "The server has gone away" means you lost your connection *after it was already established successfully.* This can happen when mysqld crashes. There are lots of possible causes for crashes, but one I've seen is table corruption, which can be repaired with mysqlcheck.

Comment: I had this error many times before and reconnecting has always solved it until now.The strange thing about this time is that the error occurs immediately after connection, even a few milliseconds. MySQL had not crashed, it was still alive and well and the tables were not corrupt. I have read that MySQL does not treat localhost the same as 127.0.0.1. I don't know why, but my experience confirms this. Making this change solved the problem. "localhost" worked on Ubuntu, but I had to use "127.0.0.1" on CentOS. That's all I know.

Comment: re: the difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost: if you connect to `localhost` mysql will use a unix socket connection and if you connect to 127.0.0.1 mysql will use TCP/IP instead.

Answer (score -1):

Solved. I changed the host from localhost to 127.0.0.1 and it worked.